# How do I add these two variables?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "first number please"
first = gets.chomp

puts "Second number please"
second = gets.chomp

answer = first + second
puts "The calculation is #{first} + #{second} = " + answer.to_s
```

I summed two variables `first` and `second`

If `first` == 1 and `second` == 2 then `answer` should be 3, but ruby shows 12 What is the problem?

What I tried is

```
answer = first.+(second)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thant's because `gets` returns a string. So the `+` operator in `answer = first + second` applies to string concatenation. Change it to:

```
puts "first number please"
first = gets.to_i
puts "Second number please"
second = gets.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is that you are trying to get sum of 2 strings which is not going to work, you need to first turn it into a integer by replacing `.chomp` with `.to_i` and then you can use it like you were using it, but remember that if you want decimal number for example if you are doing division you need to use `.to_f` to make it float to get the more accurate answer in decimals

```rb
puts("Give first number")
number_one = gets.to_i
puts("Give second number")
number_two = gets.to_i
sum = number_one + number_two
puts("Answer is: #{sum}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers you got were actually strings, so when you used "+" ruby concatenated them. 
You should try

```
gets.to_i
```

Answer (score -1):

```
puts "first number please"
first = gets.chomp
puts "Second number please"
second = gets.chomp
answer = first.to_i + second.to_i
puts "The calculation is #{first} + #{second} = #{answer}"
```

Console:

```
[3] a = gets.chomp
2
=> "2"
[4] a.class
=> String
[5] a = a.to_i
=> 2
[6] a.class
=> Fixnum
```